# Instalar biblioteca Curl Python 3.4.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, libcurl, biblioteca

Alguém possui um link do .zip para instalar a biblitoca "import pycurl"

Uso Windows e Python 3.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe [pycurl-7.19.5.1.win32-py3.4](https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/)

Extraia na pasta e execute no cmd pip install pycurlpycurl-7.19.5.1.win32-py3.4